# What does it take to build a web app that accepts an email, and posts it's contents online?

Tags: c#, email

I'm not even sure how to word the question correctly.

I have a web app, built in C#, ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor), and would like to allow members to send an email from their mobile device, to one of my app's e-mail addresses. Then my app posts the contents of the e-mail to the site.

I'd like the email address to be their username + domain.com.

Can this be done strictly from code within my web app, hosted on DiscountASP shared hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options for receiving email and a lot of it depends on what your host supports and how many emails you need to receive. I wrote a [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/) describing the options for Rails apps. The options are pretty much identical for C# apps although if you're using windows you might have to substitute what you actually run in the command line.

The main options include polling an existing email server using POP/IMAP, making your email server execute a script when it receives a message or using a third party like CloudMailin to make and HTTP Post to your app with the message content.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a mail server to handle the incoming mail and store it on the server for you. Your ASP web app could then read the email files server side, process the data, and  update your site with it.

Comment: So the host's email server can be setup to store the emails to a folder accessible to my web app?

Comment: Yes that should be the case. Your emails should be going to a folder on your hosting that your web app can read. Try asking your provider where your emails are being written to.